# Mouse position doesn't match to JavaScript chart cursor

Tags: amcharts

I'm using Amcharts JavaScript library in Windows application (Xojo,HTMLViewer). It works well.
However, I have an issue.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e68evm1f0selw2p/IMG_0396.jpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgge5kiz1x87qj9/IMG_0397.jpg?dl=0

Mouse position doesn't match to the cursor of Charts, all the time mouse stands leftside of it when I increase the Windows size.
In opposite, when I decrease the windows size, mouse position is right side.
When I start my application for the first time, it matches correctly but in case I increase or maximize the Windows screen, this issue happens.

Do you think this is an issue of HTMLViewer or Amcharts?

Any workaround would be helpful.

Comment: Does this happen when you run this same chart directly in browser?

Comment: No. There is no issue in browser. I think Chart's cursor gets the mouse x,y point when it is loaded first, so application screen is changed, it doesn't seem to change it accordingly.

Comment: I tried to reload the Chart ( location.reload()). It works now. Thank you.